# logon denied for oracle wallet user

Tags: docker, node.js, oracle-19c, wallet

Following a video tutorial on oracle wallets: https://youtu.be/LLZzUNb9ALU

The db server is run from oracle's official docker container.

The steps I have done are as follows:

1. On server shell, ran sql plus as sysdba:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

2. Created a user:

```sql
SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
SQL> CREATE USER fred identified by flintstone;
SQL> GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA to fred;
```

3. Tested logon:

```
$ sqlplus fred/flintstone

SQL> show user;
User is "fred"
```

4. Created a wallet at default location: `$ORACLE_BASE/admin/$ORACLE_SID/wallet`

```
$ orapki wallet create -wallet $ORACLE_BASE/admin/$ORACLE_SID/wallet -auto_login -pwd MyWalletPass
```

5. Created a wallet profile for user `fred`:

```
$ mkstore -wrl $ORACLE_BASE/admin/$ORACLE_SID/wallet -createCredential $ORACLE_SID fred flintstone
```

6. Tried to login sqlplus:

```
$ sqlplus /@$ORACLE_SID
```

This fails. Got the error `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

Not able to understand whats wrong. The final goal is to use this wallet for a nodejs application with external auth (node-oracledb). But I think if I can fix step 6 I should be able to use from nodejs.

Comment: Why did you set that internal parameter to pretend that this is an Oracle owned user? You should be creating your users in a pluggable database not the root container. Your use of $ORACLE_SID when a tnsnames entry is required is very confusing, I suggest you don’t use an environment variable (and confirm it points to the pluggable DB you create the user in). Have you pointed to your wallet from your sqlnet config? I suggest you read https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/secure-external-password-store-10gr2

Comment: Did not do anything with sqlnet.ora since the location where the wallet is created is one of the default locations oracle searches for wallets.

Comment: Is this all on the database server? Is the $ORACLE_HOME for the client different that the $ORACLE_HOME for the DB, and if so which one did you put the wallet in? I would second what Andrew said as well: never rely on "defaults"; they can vary by version or product. Always specify your configuration explicitly in your sqlnet.ora file. The next person who comes along may have no idea where the default locations are, or that you used a wallet at all, much less where you put it, unless you document that in your configuration.

Comment: Can you include your client sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora, and confirm whether the client connection is originating from the database server itself, or from a separate application server?

Comment: I have done the following two things: explicitly specified the wallet location in `sqlnet.ora` file, and, included the line `SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE=TRUE` in the same file. Post which I can `sqlplus` as mentioned in #6. Now the issue still remains in next steps (i.e in the nodejs app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Andrew](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282458/logon-denied-for-oracle-wallet-user#comment552178_282458)

The 1st part, I explicitly mentioned wallet location in `sqlnet.ora` file, and also included the following line:`SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE=TRUE`. Also verified the correct tns entry in `tnsnames.ora`. (This is already taken care of during container start, so I didn't have to do anything).

For the 2nd part, I had to use the same `sqlnet.ora` with the exception that the `WALLET_LOCATION` parameter was updated with the location to the wallet folder on the client machine. And for the client program, I had to set the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable; I had to point it to the folder where the former file would reside. Additionally added a `tnsnames.ora` file and added a tns name (similar to the oracle service name on the db server).

**Note**: On the client machine, we have to be careful of the syntax in the `sqlnet.ora` and the `tnsnames.ora` file. Different clients have various ways to connect. I have just noted for the case of a nodejs program which used `orcaledb` as the oracle client. These specific type of clients make use of the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN`.